# QThread with pointer to pointer

Tags: pointers, qt-creator, qthread

I have a problem with QThread.
I did some calculation in GUI thread and it worked.
But now I try to do a calculation in work thread and there is a runtime error.

A have this function.

```
double **matrix(int nx,int ny, int shift)
{
    int i;
    double **m=(double **)calloc(nx+1, sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0;i<=nx;i++) m[i]=(double *)calloc(ny+1,sizeof(double))+shift;
    return m+shift;
}
```

And in run() function a want to do this:

```
double **lop=matrix(1,2,3);
```

But in this line there is this error: SIGSEGV  Segmentation fault.
A don't understand, why the error is only in the work thread. Because when run this in GUI thread, it works.

Excuse me please my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't shift by 3. You must have things aligned to the word boundaries. Words are two bytes so the shift can only be an even number. Perhaphs you want

```
return m + shift*sizeof(double*);
```